# Convert HTML to NSAttributedString in Background?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I am working on an app that will retrieve posts from WordPress and allow the user to view each post individually, in detail. The WordPress API brings back the post content which is the HTML of the post. (Note: the img tags are referencing the WordPress URL of the uploaded image)

Originally, I was using a WebView & loading the retrieved content directly into it. This worked great; however, the images seemed to be loading on the main thread, as it caused lag & would sometimes freeze the UI until the image had completed downloading. I was suggested to check out the Aztec Editor library from WordPress; however, I could not understand how to use it (could not find much documentation).

My current route is parsing the HTML content and creating a list of dictionaries (keys of type [image or text] and content). Once it is parsed, I build out the post by dynamically adding Labels & Image views (which allows me to download images in background). While this does seem overly-complex & probably the wrong route, it is working well (would be open to any other solutions, though!) My only issue currently is the delay of converting an HTML string to NSAttributedText. Before adding the text content to the dictionary, I will convert it from a String to an NSAttributedString. I have noticed a few seconds delay & the CPU of the simulator getting up to 50-60% for a few seconds, then dropping. Is there anyway I could do this conversion on a background thread(s) and display a loading animation during this time?

Please let me know if you have any ideas or suggestions for a better solution. Thank you very much!

Code:

```
let postCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()
var yPos = CGFloat(20)
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

...

 func parsePost() -> [[String:Any]]? {
    if let postFromCache = postCache.object(forKey: postToView.id as NSString) as? [[String:Any]] {
        return postFromCache
    } else {
        var content = [[String:Any]]()

        do {
            let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(postToView.postContent)
            if let elements = try doc.body()?.children() {
                for elem in elements {
                    if(elem.hasText()) {
                        do {
                            let html = try elem.html()
                            if let validHtmlString = html.htmlToAttributedString {
                                content.append(["text" : validHtmlString])
                            }
                        } 
                    } else {
                        let imageElements = try elem.getElementsByTag("img")
                        if(imageElements.size() > 0) {
                            for image in imageElements {
                                var imageDictionary = [String:Any]()
                                let width = (image.getAttributes()?.get(key: "width"))!
                                let height = (image.getAttributes()?.get(key: "height"))!
                                let ratio = CGFloat(Float(height)!/Float(width)!)
                                imageDictionary["ratio"] = ratio
                                imageDictionary["image"] = (image.getAttributes()?.get(key: "src"))!

                                content.append(imageDictionary)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

        if(content.count > 0) {
            postCache.setObject(content as AnyObject, forKey: postToView.id as NSString)
        }

        return content
    }
}

func buildUi(content: [[String:Any]]) {
    for dict in content {
        if let attributedText = dict["text"] as? NSAttributedString {
            let labelToAdd = UILabel()
            labelToAdd.attributedText = attributedText
            labelToAdd.numberOfLines = 0
            labelToAdd.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:yPos, width: 200, height: 0)
            labelToAdd.sizeToFit()
            yPos += labelToAdd.frame.height + 5
            self.scrollView.addSubview(labelToAdd)
        } else if let imageName = dict["image"] as? String {
            let ratio = dict["ratio"] as! CGFloat
            let imageToAdd = UIImageView()
            let url = URL(string: imageName)
            Nuke.loadImage(with: url!, into: imageToAdd)
            imageToAdd.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:yPos, width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth*ratio)
            yPos += imageToAdd.frame.height + 5
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageToAdd)
        }
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: yPos)
}

extension String {
var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
var htmlToString: String {
    return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
```

}

( Forgive me for the not-so-clean code! I am just wanting to make sure I can achieve a desirable outcome before I start refactoring. Thanks again! )

Comment: `init(data:options:documentsAttributes:)` might take time, but according to the doc, it should be done in Main Thread (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-init)